# to get the no of records from my database and store it in an integer

Tags: android, database, count

I want to get the count of the records from the database onto my app in an integer then display it...
how do i do that???

i am not able to do so

here is the database code

```
public int counttable()
{
    int count=0;
    openOrCreateDatabase();

    count=db.execSQL("select count(*) from "+TableNameis+";");

    return count;

}
```

i know that the datatypes dont match...can anyone please suggest how do i do that??
how do i store the count value in an integer variable.

**Dashboard.java**

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity {

EditText edt_pending, edt_completed,edt_synched;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    edt_pending=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpending);
    edt_completed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editcompleted);
    edt_synched=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editsynched);

    WayDataBase way=new WayDataBase(Dashboard.this);
    int count=way.counttable();

    edt_completed.setText(count);


}
```

}

**logcat**

`04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to        start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.lthomepage/com.android.lthomepage.Dashboard}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3640)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at com.android.lthomepage.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:27)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public int counttable()
{
int count=0;
openOrCreateDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from your_table_name",null);
count=c.getCount();
return count;
}
```

Also,

```
edt_completed.setText(String.valueOf(count));
```

Using SELECT query is enough, then count the size of Cursor..

Comment: unfortunately the app has stopped..call to my database function is `WayDataBase way=new WayDataBase(getApplicationContext());
  int count=way.counttable();`....have i done something wrong here??? coz the error in the logcat is Resource not found exception

Comment: 04-08 07:15:02.216: E/AndroidRuntime(16026): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.lthomepage/com.android.lthomepage.Dashboard}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Comment: in the Dashboard class all the database access is in the onCreate function....is it becaouse of that there is force close??

Comment: Share your code and log error. I can't understand the error without your code

Comment: try edt_completed.setText(String.valueOf(count));

Comment: yeah it worked! thanks a lot for your effort! can u tel me whether i can find the count of records for multiple tables in the same query??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Cursor#getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29) to get the count of the no. of records.

```
public int counttable()
{
    int count=0;
    openOrCreateDatabase();

    // count=db.execSQL("select * from "+TableNameis+";"); - This statement is invalid

    // Use this instead
    count=db.rawQuery(selectionQuery, null).getCount(); 

    return count;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create One Class for DatabaseCreate Like this..

   public class WayDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
   {

   ```
   private static String DATABASE_NAME = "Database Name";
   private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
   private Context myContext;
   private String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/"Package Name"/databases/";


   // Constructor  

   public WayDataBase (Context context) 
   {

       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
       this.myContext = context;
   }

   // Create DataBase 

   public void createDatabase() throws IOException
   {

       boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

       if(dbExist)
       {
       }
       else
       {

           this.getReadableDatabase();

           try 
           {
               this.close();   
               copyDataBase();
           } 
           catch (IOException e) 
           {
               throw new Error("Error copying database");
           }
       }

   }

   // check Database Existing or not

   private boolean checkDataBase() 
   {
       SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

       try
       {
           String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
           checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

       }
       catch(SQLiteException e)
       {
       }

       if(checkDB != null)
       {

           checkDB.close();

       }

       return checkDB != null ? true : false;

   }

   // Copy DataBase from assets to SD card 

   private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
   {

       String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;


       OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
       InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int length;
       while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) 
       {
           myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
       }

       myInput.close();
       myOutput.flush();
       myOutput.close();
   }

   // Open DataBase

   public void openDatabase() throws SQLException
   {

       String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
       myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

   }
   public int counttable()
   {
       int count=0;
       openDatabase();
       Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name",null);
       return count;
   }
   ```

   }

Now in your Activity

public class Dashboard extends Activity
 {

private WayDataBase way;

```
EditText edt_pending, edt_completed,edt_synched;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    edt_pending=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpending);
    edt_completed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editcompleted);
    edt_synched=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editsynched);


    way= new WayDataBase(this);
    try 
    {
        way.createDatabase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) 
    {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }


    int count=way.counttable();

    edt_completed.setText(count+"");


}
```

}

Comment: U have to put your table name